# VS Code Terminal is blank / not-useable

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

For the last 2-3 weeks, my VS Code terminal has been blank. Not sure when it exactly started or what might have changed to cause this.

I usually use GIT Bash as my default terminal in VS Code, but this happens even if i switch to CMD or Powershell.

I have already uninstalled/reinstalled VS Code (did not solve the issue).
I have also seen this issue online, but no real solution seems to be out there.
Is there some VS Code setting i can fiddle with to try and fix it?

[image]

Also, When i have VS Code open to a project, I do get a file put into my project folder named `bash.exe.stackdump` which some very odd numerical info dump. Nothing easy to decode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have solved this issue.
I unchecked the compatibility mode in VS Code properties where it says Run this program in compatibility mode for:

Comment: Hi there, consider adding some images to showcase what you are trying to explain.

Comment: He is talking about right clicking the VSCode icon on WIndows desktop to open VSCode Properties menu, and unchecking the compatibility mode (dropdown).